# ASP.NET Core 5 & Entity Framework : convention based navigation problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that uses Entity Framework with convention based navigation and it works great. I decided to experiment moving
to ASP.NET Core 5 with Entity Framework Core v5.0.6. Well not easy, what a bear as the conventions for one to many break down. Afraid to try my many-to-many!

I have extended `IdentityUser` to include a navigation property of `List<BookedDates>` :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
        public int skillLevel { get; set; }
        public int timesCaptain { get; set; }
        public int bFreezeDB { get; set; }
        public string memberName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<BookedDates> bookedDates { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Match> Matches { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            bFreezeDB = 0;
        }
}
```

Now a user can have many `BookDates`:

```
public class BookedDates
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ApplicationUser user { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

The initial migration code looks good as seems to have picked up foreign key relations:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "statusforDays",
            columns: table => new
            {
                id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                month = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                status = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ApplicationUserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_statusforDays", x => x.id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_statusforDays_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId",
                    column: x => x.ApplicationUserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Then in my Controller I make following call:

```
ApplicationUser user = _db.Users
                          .Include(u => u.bookedDates)
                          .Where(u => u.Email == email)
                          .SingleOrDefault();
```

I get this error:

> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll but was not handled in user code
> Invalid column name 'userId'.

Where is `userid` coming from? I know I can probably use Fluent and create the relation but I thought EF Core 5 was supposed to handle simple convention based navigation much better than v3

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest the FluentApi approach because this gives you more control over the relations.

In your `BookedDates` class you have the navigation property: `public virtual ApplicationUser user { get; set; }`. By convention EF Core search the name of the property followed by `Id` as a foreign key column: `userId` like the error shows.

Rename  the property as `public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }` and the convention will search for `ApplicationUserId` field in the table instead `userId`.

Comment: Then mark response as solution, please. Someone down vote the response without comment the reason.